# Why isn't my for loop working java?

Tags: java

This code doesn't work for some reason in Java:

```
for(i =6; i<9; i++)
System.out.println(i);
```

Why isn't this working? Thank you!

Comment: I don't know what that means..

Comment: I do not know what "not working" means.

Comment: Sorry - it's just not printing 6, 7, and 8. I apologize for this!

Comment: Look at the anwser's :). Sombody said the solution.

Comment: you shall use an IDE and it will tell you why you can't compile

Comment: In the future, to avoid a deluge of down votes, I suggest a couple of things.  1) Make sure you post *exactly* what your problem is (doesn't print anything, prints something wrong, crashes with an error).  2)  Add any and all relevant error messages from either the compiler or the running of the program.

Comment: Thank you, Ian! I will keep it in mind. Sorry for being so annoying!

Comment: @user3149663 Don't worry about it.  You're not being annoying.  This site really just isn't terribly new-user-friendly, I'm afraid, with its own little subculture.  Kind of like someone new going to Reddit and trying to be clever with five year old memes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part of a for loop works like a regular line of code in Java. Think of it as the following:

```
i = 6;
//your for loop
```

However `i = 6` is not a valid Java line of code as you have not yet declared `i`.

Replacing it with a declaration: `int i = 6` , however, is valid, so edit your loop as such:

```
for(int i = 6; i<9; i++)
    System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: Well, it's valid, if an earlier statement declared `i`.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to declare the variable `i`. So it should be:

```
for(int i=6; i<9; i++) {
System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: Why the quotation marks?

Comment: And well, you can't instantiate an integer. You declare it.

Comment: is this significant to use "declare" instead of "instantiate" when talking about integers?

Comment: @akonsu *Technically,* the word "instantiate" implies a constructor running and an object being created.  But it's a bit of a pedantic nuance, especially for *this* question. :)

Comment: Yes. Instantiation is the process of creating an object. Declaration is the process of telling the compiler that a symbol is a variable with a specific type.

Comment: No better time to understand the distinction, than when just starting out. It'll matter a good deal.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to declare the variable as an `int`. So try this:

```
for(int i = 6; i < 9; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```